# How to stop VScode Python from breaking indexing brackets?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have been using some autoformatting in VScode (through modification of `settings.json`) and it's really convenient. However, one thing that pisses me off is that it often times **breaks my indexing brackets**, and I am fairly sure it is **way before hitting the max-line-length limit**.

As an example, what I want is:

```
if some_function(some_array[batch_idx, ...],
                 input_kwarg1=some_other_array[batch_idx, sample_idx, :],
                 input_kwarg2=something_else):
    another_array[batch_idx, sample_idx, :] = something
```

What VScode autoformatting gives me is:

```
if some_function(some_array[batch_idx, ...],
                 input_kwarg1=some_other_array[batch_idx,
                                               sample_idx, :],
                 input_kwarg2=something_else):
   another_array[batch_idx, sample_idx,
                 :] = something
```

This ugliness triggers me a lot. Experiencing deteriorated mental health.

Is there any idea which parameter I can modify in `settings.json` to prevent this annoying behavior?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure what the answer is, but my recommendation is to stop futzing around with this, embrace an opinionated auto-formatter like [Black](https://pypi.org/project/black/), and let it do its thing. Stop worrying about formatting. Beauty and ugliness are both in the eye of the beholder, so get used to something fairly standard.

Comment: Also, are you using built-in VSCode auto-formatting or Black? If not, as Chris recommended, I'd use black.

Comment: I am using the `yapf` formatter. Yeah I can try out Black.

Comment: *deteriorated mental health.* in this context seems a bit trivializing to those facing actual real life MH challenges.  Second black suggestion for the rest, reliance on editor-bound settings will be brittle if others edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the following items in your VScode `settings.json` file to solve where the "editor max-column" effects kick in:

```js
"editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 79
```